# Why is Hibernate throwing subquery returned more than 1 value?

Tags: sql, hibernate

I know this type of question has been asked before but I'm fairly new to hibernate and it's hard for me to understand this case. So im using this @formula in Hibernate and this is the class: Does `@ManyToOne` mapping have anything to do with it?

So i have an entity class something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ABC")
public class ABC{

    @Id
    @Column(name ="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="AMOUNT")
    private Double amount

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "R_ID")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private TXY txy;

    @Formula((SELECT (abc.AMOUNT + ( abc.AMOUNT * ISNULL(tx.RATE,0) )) FROM ABC abc left join TXY tx on abc.R_ID = tx.ORIGINAL_R_ID WHERE abc.ID = ID)")
    @Getter
    private Double taxAmount;


}
```

This subquery return more than 1 value :

```
SELECT (abc.AMOUNT + ( abc.AMOUNT * ISNULL(tx.RATE,0) )) 
FROM ABC abc 
left join TXY tx on abc.R_ID = tx.ORIGINAL_R_ID 
WHERE abc.ID = ID
```

i get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Subquery returned more than 1 value.  This is illegal when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=, or when the subquery is used as an expression.
        net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getNextRow(TdsCore.java:805)
    net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.next(JtdsResultSet.java:611)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:191)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:191)
    net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.ResultSetSpy.next(ResultSetSpy.java:1203)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:950)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:126)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1718)
    org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:380)
    com.abcd.tfc.repositories.tfcRepositoryImpl.launchCriteria(tfcRepositoryImpl.java:151)
    com.abcd.tfc.repositories.tfcRepositoryImpl.findAllWithCriteriaDecorator(tfcRepositoryImpl.java:112)
    com.abcd.tfc.repositories.tfcRepositoryImpl.findAllWithCriteriaDecorator(tfcRepositoryImpl.java:102)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor369.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:401)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:373)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:486)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy168.findAllWithCriteriaDecorator(Unknown Source)
    com.tfc.business.util.AbstractBusinessBO.findAllWithCriteriaDecorator(AbstractBusinessBO.java:268)
    com.tfc.business.util.AbstractBusinessBO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$be9ea55d.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    com.tfc.business.bo.InvoiceBusiness$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef1e7ae1.findAllWithCriteriaDecorator(<generated>)
    com.tfc.business.util.AbstractBusinessBO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$be9ea55d.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    com.tfc.business.bo.InvoiceBusiness$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f6253b14.findAllWithCriteriaDecorator(<generated>)
    com.tfc.business.bo.RecentlyViewedBusiness.findAllRecentlyViewed(RecentlyViewedBusiness.java:522)
    com.tfc.business.bo.RecentlyViewedBusiness.getRecentlyViewed(RecentlyViewedBusiness.java:124)
    com.tfc.business.bo.RecentlyViewedBusiness$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f19d458f.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    com.tfc.business.bo.RecentlyViewedBusiness$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$20d96d2c.getRecentlyViewed(<generated>)
    com.tfc.business.bo.RecentlyViewedBusiness$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f19d458f.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    com.tfc.business.bo.RecentlyViewedBusiness$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d230ffd9.getRecentlyViewed(<generated>)
    com.tfc.web.bean.RecentlyViewedBean.getRecents(RecentlyViewedBean.java:220)
    com.tfc.web.bean.RecentlyViewedBean.getRecents(RecentlyViewedBean.java:216)
    com.tfc.web.bean.RecentlyViewedBean.getRecentInvoices(RecentlyViewedBean.java:702)
    com.tfc.web.bean.RecentlyViewedBean$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fa121570.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    com.tfc.web.bean.RecentlyViewedBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$915e83ce.getRecentInvoices(<generated>)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:94)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ForEachHandler.apply(ForEachHandler.java:164)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
```

I would greatly appreciate any help and advice.

Comment: The error is clear: your formula query is returning more than one value.  If we knew your data, perhaps an alternative query could be given.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's the thing when i run this query in sql with a hard coded Id example `where invc.ID =7777`. it only give me one result.
Does `@ManyToOne` play a role here?

Comment: If even one query returns 2 or more values it will fail.  Your test only showed that it passed for a certain invoice, not necessarily for all of them.

Comment: You could try adding rownum=1 to your sub query

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks. I'll test it out again.

Comment: @grahamh I can try that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not intimately familiar with Hibernate, but this query is suspicious:

```
SELECT (abc.AMOUNT + ( abc.AMOUNT * ISNULL(tx.RATE,0) ))
FROM ABC abc left join
     TXY tx
     on abc.R_ID = tx.ORIGINAL_R_ID
WHERE abc.ID = ID
---------------^
```

In most SQL compilers, this `ID` is going to be resolved within the query, as `abc.ID`.  Hence, all rows in `abc` with non-`NULL` `ID`s will be returned.

I prefix outer variables with something like `v_` so they don't interfere with other identifiers.